# Python solver for a linear objective function with quadratic constraints

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, numerical-optimization, python, qclp

I need to optimize a problem of the following form within Python

$ minimize$

$\qquad abs(\Delta w) \;\epsilon^T$

$s.t.$

$\qquad(w+\Delta w)C(w+\Delta w)^T \; \le 9500 (some\; finite\; number) \\\\[2ex]
\qquad\frac{\Delta w_i}{w_i} \gt -1 \; \forall\; i$

$\text{w = Vector of weights}$

$\Delta\text{w = Vector of change in weights}$

$\epsilon\text{ = Vector of costs}$

$\text{C = Variance Covariance matrix}$

Comment: Welcome to MSE ! Your question, as stated, is quite large : could you explain what you have tried, and what you have trouble with? By the way, if your question is about how to write a program solving the problem in Python, it is off-topic here.

Comment: I'm not looking at the Python code per se, I mentioned it so that that the bounds on complexity is defined.

I am basically trying to solve a linear minimization problem with quadratic constraints.
By definition, techniques like Simplex do not work, and  methods like Newton-Raphson may not converge. Hence would like to pick brains on what other techniques I should be trying
I can find a lot of material on quadratic functions with linear constraints, but not vice versa